# selenium chrome webdriver dosent work on pycharm

Tags: selenium

this is the code:

```
import os
from selenium import webdriver

os.environ['PATH'] += r"C:/SeleniumDrivers"
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
```

im going by a guide on youtube from freecodecamp. i've done everything they said. i installed chrime webdriver and all.  yet i get this error:

```
:\Users\yaniv\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:\Users\yaniv\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\main.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\yaniv\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 71, in start
    self.process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, env=self.env,
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\yaniv\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\subprocess.py", line 1022, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "C:\Users\yaniv\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\subprocess.py", line 1491, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

im going by a guide from freecodecamp like i said. im trying to find a solution but i cant find anything anywhere

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

This code will be a good example for starting point.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

executable_path="your chromedriver path"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(executable_path))
```